# Always use default fonts in Chromium

Tags: chromium

In Firefox, there is an option to `Allow sites to choose their own fonts`, which, when disabled, always uses the default fonts. Does this preference have an equivilant in Chromium?

**PS:** I'm using [`ungoogled-chromium`](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium)

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'd like to disable custom fonts, so every page uses the default monospace/serif/sans-serif fonts

Comment: This question does not seem to be related with Ubuntu, but rather just the browsers in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse to

```
chrome://settings/fonts
```

Choose the default font and size you want to use on all webpages.

Personally, I would not recommend doing so because it may break webpages that use custom fonts.

Comment: This works to change the font size, but changing the font family doesn't have an effect... In firefox, it's possible to disable custom fonts (which resolves any font rendering issues), but I can't find a chromium equivilant